# Proving $\rho(A,B)\le \rho(x,A)+\rho(x,B)$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that:

$$\rho(A,B)\le \rho(x,A)+\rho(x,B).$$

Where $\rho$ denotes the distance.

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: What is your definition of $\rho(A,B)$? Is $R=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @mathmax: Yes, it is.

Comment: @Paul And the definition of $\rho(A,B)$??

Comment: @gebruiker: It denotes the distance from A to B :)

Comment: @Paul There can be more than one way to define the distance between two elements of a set. We need to now what definition you are using i.e. how does one calculate the distance between two given $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Paul This is not a definition, it's the intuition behind it.

Comment: O, sorry, I don't know...

Comment: @Paul Suppose $A=\mathbb{R}^2\subset\mathbb{R}^m$, $A=\mathbb{R}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_m\end{pmatrix}$, then what does your textbook say $\rho(A,x)$ and $\rho(A,B)$ should be and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed is here that the sets $A$ and $B$ are not empy.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and find $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ with $\rho\left(x,a\right)\leq\rho\left(x,A\right)+\varepsilon$
and $\rho\left(x,b\right)\leq\rho\left(x,B\right)+\varepsilon$.

Then:
$$\rho\left(A,B\right)\leq\rho\left(a,b\right)\leq\rho\left(x,a\right)+\rho\left(x,b\right)\leq\rho\left(x,A\right)+\rho\left(x,B\right)+2\varepsilon$$
This is true for each $\varepsilon>0$ hence: $$\rho\left(A,B\right)\leq\rho\left(x,A\right)+\rho\left(x,B\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Take any $a \in A$, $b \in B$. Then

$$\rho(A, B) \leq \rho(a, b) \leq \rho(a, x) + \rho(x,b) .$$

Why does this prove your claim?

EDIT: I assume that $\rho(A, B) = \inf_{a \in A, b\in B} \rho(a, b)$ and analogously for $\rho(x, A)$.